# Reloading image in javascript without any parameter-hack

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display an image and automatically refresh it every minute using AngularJS.

The problem is that the image I am grabbing is from an API that won't allow me to append any bogus stuff to the url to make the url different each time. So, no `?_ts=12356678` and so on...

The current code I have is something like this:

HTML template:

```
<div data-ng-controller="UpdateController" data-ng-init="image_reloader(timer=2000, url='http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/')">
  <img ng-src="{{ image_url }}"></img>
</div>
```

AngularJS Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('UpdateController', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.image_reloader = function(timer, url) {
    $scope.timer = timer || 10000;
    $scope.updater = function() {
      $scope.image_url = url + '?_ts=' + new Date().getTime();
      $timeout($scope.updater, $scope.timer);
    };
    $scope.updater();
  };
});
```

This kind of does the trick, except for the `?_ts` part which I can't use... Changing the `scope.image_url` part to `$scope.image_url = url;` doesn't do anything, it does not try to refresh the image either.

How can I force AngularJS to try to refresh it? I've also tried to set `$scope.image_url` to `''` before changing it to url.

AngularJS is just the framework, any Javascript/jQuery solution would do, but I prefer an AngularJS-related one.

Comment: Image is cached by the browser, so I don't think you can't really do anything to clear the cache (unless you want to do a full reload). Btw, quite lame API you got there.

Comment: I am getting a new image every time I refresh the lorempixel image in the example. The example doesn’t have any caching headers. Does that mean that the only way to do this is with a full page reload? If this question is going nowhere, I am writing the API provider a mail telling them about this problem.. :)

Comment: You can try to set a cache header on the server the image is hosted.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to share the solution. It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sent the vendor of this API a request for adding a dummy parameter so this would be possible, but its been a month now, and no reply.

I've also been thinking about this, and finally found a solution. It is as simple as just using the # sign instead of ?. The hash is never sent to the server, but is still enough for the JavaScript to see it as a different request and hence refetch the image..
Little embarrassed to not have thought about that before now :)

Example (using the workflow I'm doing for this project, not AngularJS optimal

Angular code:

```
$scope.image_reloader = function(timer, url) {
  $scope.timer = timer || 10000;
  $scope.updater = function() {
    $scope.image_url = url + '#' + new Date().getTime();
    $timeout($scope.updater, $scope.timer);
  };
  $scope.updater();
};
```

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="UpdateController" ng-init="image_reloader(timer=2000, url='http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/')">
  <img ng-src="[[ image_url ]]"></img>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work... note that this isn't tested and you may need to add or subtract 1 from questionMarkIndex.

```
var questionMarkIndex = $scope.image_url.indexOf("?");
var newurl = (questionMarkIndex  === -1 ? $scope.image_url : $scope.image_url.substring(0, questionMarkIndex); // remove old ts parameter
newurl += '?_ts=' + new Date().getTime();
$scope.image_url += newurl;
```

Comment: The whole problem is that I cant append my own parameters to the url because the API wont allow it. So this wont work.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you request another image from the API. I'm suggesting you append the timestamp to the image_url after you get that url from the server. Not sure if the syntax is correct because there's very little code context.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. But it’s the img tag that initialize the GET from to the remote API, so I cant fool it like that. Where I store the url locally needs to be what I reach out to get..